# If Function is a set of ordered pairs then why do we call it as a rule?

Tags: calculus, relations

I am confused here with the vocabulary we use while defining functions. If function f is a set of ordered pairs, then what is meant by a function f is a Rule which which produce new elelments out of some given elements.Why do we have two definitions of function.

Comment: The latter definition isn't rigorous but is generally more understandable at first; the former definition is more precise, but more abstract. They just have different audiences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the concept of function $f$ from a set $A$ into a set $B$ is introduced for the first time, it is usually described as a rule that converts each element of $A$ into an element of $B$. This is just an idea of what a function is. It cannot be a definition unless we then define the meaning of the word “rule”.

So, we have the formal definition of a function $f$ from a set $A$ into a set $B$ as a subset of $A\times B$ such that, for each $a\in A$, there is one and only $b$ in $B$ such that $(a,b)\in f$. And then we introduce the notation $f(a)$ (with $a\in A$), which means that only element $b\in B$ such that $(a,b)\in f$. This definition may be hard to understand at first, but it is a real definition (that is, it is not just an attempt to explain the meaning of the word).

Comment: Sir, a function f:A⟶B is a set of ordered pairs, so sir this is the original defination of what a function is Right ?

Comment: It's not *any* set of ordered pairs. It's, as I wrote in my answer, a set of ordered pairs from $A\times B$ such that, for each $a\in A$, there is one and only one $b\in B$ such that $(a,b)$ belongs to that set.

Comment: Yes Sir, I understand thisa function f:A⟶B  is a set of ordered pairs from A×B such that, for each a∈A, there is one and only one b∈B such that (a,b) belongs to set f. I was asking that this is the original defination of what a function is Right ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: So, sir we can say that a function set f can represented by an equation such as f(x)=2x .

Comment: Not without a domain and a codomain. But, if you are talking about the function $f\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=2x$. then that's fine. The$$f=\{(x,2x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}\subset\Bbb R\times\Bbb R.$$

Comment: Sir, if the function set f can represented by an equation such as f(x)=2x by- f:R⟶R defined by f(x)=2x. then why many people start saying f(x)=2x as function, we know that function set f is represented by this equation f(x)=2x. So, f(x)=2x just the representation not the function then why many people start saying f(x)=2x.

Comment: Because it is much shorter and easier to understand what we are talking about if we talk about the function$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\Bbb R&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&2x\end{array}$$than if you talk about the function$$f=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid y=2x\}.$$

Comment: Okay now I got it, People say this equation (rule) a function because this equation can  produce our function set f.So,Originally we know function is a set                                 
  f={(x,f(x):x∈R,f(x)∈R},we write f:R⟶R, f(x)=2x  because this equation can produce our function set f. So, for convienence instead of writing our function  Set f={(x,f(x):x∈R,f(x)∈R we represent this Set f by this equation  f(x)=2x and call this equation a function.Sir please tell me am I correct ?

Comment: Yes, except that I would never say that $f(x)=2x$ is an equation. It is an equality. But that's not very important.

Comment: Thankyou Sir for your help really it means a lot, whay it means "I would never say that f(x)=2x is an equation. It is an equality".

Comment: What can I say? I would not call it an equation because it is *not* an equation. It's the same reason why I would not call “chair” to an elephant.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos In your example of defining $f$ as $\{(x,2x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}\subset\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$, you've defined $f$ as a set of ordered pairs, but I don't see how you've specified the codomain? For example I could write $f=\{(x,2x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}\subset\Bbb R\times\Bbb C$, and this set would be exactly identical to the set you've constructed. But normally we'd say these 2 functions are different, one with codomain $\mathbb{R}$ and one with codomain $\mathbb{C}$. But since you've defined the function $f$ to be exactly this set, there's no way to tell them apart?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It's like if I defined a constant $x$ by $x = 1 \in \mathbb{N}$. Then "$\in \mathbb{N}$" part adds nothing to definition of $x$, which is simply "$x = 1$". There is no difference between writing $x = 1 \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x = 1 \in \mathbb{R}$. How to fix this?

Comment: @SenZen The codomain is $\Bbb R$. Not that I did not simply write $f=\{(x,2x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$; I've added $\subset\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ after that. I Meant that $f$ was a function from, say $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb C$, then I would have added $\subset\Bbb R\times\Bbb C$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I understand what you're trying to do, I'm saying it doesn't technically formally make sense. Adding "$\subset\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$" or "$\subset\Bbb R\times\Bbb C$" doesn't change anything to the definition of $f$ IF you define $f$ as a set of ordered pairs and nothing else, which is what the notation suggests. Just in the same way, $x = 1 \in \mathbb{N}$ is an identical definition as $x = 1 \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @SenZen Please read my answer. I wrote there that “we have the formal definition of a function $f$ from a set $A$ into a set $B$ as a subset of $A\times B$ such that, for each $a\in A$, there is one and only $b$ in $B$ such that $(a,b)\in f$”. So, it is implicit that when I define a function $f$ as a Cartesian product $A\times B$, then the domain of $f$ is $A$ and the codomain is $B$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Right but the problem is you cannot extract the codomain $B$ from the Cartesian product $A \times B$. I know I'm being pedantic, but this notation confusion has always bugged me. Let me put it another way, let me define the function $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}: g(x) = 2x$. So your notation would say: $g = \{(x,2x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}\subset\Bbb R\times\Bbb C$. But is it not also correct by the definition of equality for a set that $\{(x,2x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}\subset\Bbb R\times\Bbb C = \{(x,2x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}\subset\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ ?

Comment: @SenZen Yes, you are being pedantic. And, what's more important, you are also completely correct: those two sets from your last sentence are indeed equal. My notation is indeed ambiguous, but I still suppose that there is no problem if we decide that writing “let $f=\{\cdots\}\subset A\times B$” is a short way of saying “let $f$ be the function from $A$ to $B$ defined by $f=\{\cdots\}$”.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Fair enough haha, but seriously the reason it annoys me is because then we don't actually have a way to construct an actual function, we can only postulate their existence and prove their properties assuming their existence. For example, how do we know there exists a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, such that $f(x) = 2x$ ? Easiest way to prove existence of things in math is to construct an example. So we should be able to simply construct an (the) example for $f$. Surely we should be able too, but how to actually write it out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117018/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-senzen).

Comment: José Carlos Santos, Sir  f(x) is another way of writing y, f(x) and y they both are used to represent the output of the function thats why we write f(x)=y because the both mean the same thing. Right ?

Comment: @Shashwatsingh Yes, although I don't use that notation myself.

Comment: @Shashwatsingh Was my answer useful?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes Sir

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sir f(x) and y they both are used to represent the output of the function only that why we write f(x)=y ? I want to know why we write f(x)=y ?

Comment: That has nothing to do with your original question.

Comment: yes sir, I know but could you please tell why we write  f(x)=y ? please

Comment: It's just a matter of taste and tradition. It's not deeper than that. I, for instance, almost never do that.

Answer (score 0):

The former is a rigorous definition for a function in axiomatic set theory, whereas the latter is the intuitive understanding of functions. You use terms like "rule" and "produce new elements" but these do not have a wholly rigorous definition. In math, we take for granted only basic assumptions (axioms) and logical inference rules. From these, we formally define every object we are interested in. Specifically, almost all modern math uses the axioms of set theory, under which every mathematical object is a set. In fact, even ordered pairs can be defined as [specific sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Defining_the_ordered_pair_using_set_theory). From here, we can define functions $f: A \longrightarrow B$ as a special subset $f \subseteq A \times B$ where $\forall a \exists b (a, b) \in f$ and $(a, b)\in f \text{ and } (a, b') \in f \implies b = b'$. We write $f(a)=b$ for $(a, b) \in f$.

We can continue further to make set theoretic definitions for most of the objects of modern math. By doing so, we can put math on a rigorous and uniform foundation.